# Spring Integration xpath-router support for mapping multiple values to one channel without listing all the mapping values

Tags: spring, integration

We have a Web Service Response which gives us a result attribute whose value range is 0 to 100. '0' being Success. 1 to 50 represent Warnings. 51 to 100 represent Errors.

We have to route the response to three different channels as per the result code.

Right now, I have mappings configured as shown below.

```
    <!-- Warnings -->
<int-xml:mapping value="1" channel="createContactWarningChannel" />
<int-xml:mapping value="2" channel="createContactWarningChannel" />
...
<int-xml:mapping value="50" channel="createContactWarningChannel" />

    <!-- Errors -->
<int-xml:mapping value="51" channel="createContactErrorChannel" />
<int-xml:mapping value="52" channel="createContactErrorChannel" />
...
<int-xml:mapping value="100" channel="createContactErrorChannel" />
```

Is there any clean way to route the response (Errors and Warnings) to corresponding channels without listing all those mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration routers don't support `conditional` mapping - only `value equals match`. However you get a trick from Generic Router + SpEL, the SpEL expression will evaluate to the desired channel name:

```
<int:router input-channel="routeChannel" default-output-channel="createContactChannel"
   expression="#xpath(payload, '//status') gt 0 and #xpath(payload, '//status') lt 51 ? 'createContactWarningChannel' : 'createContactErrorChannel'"/>
```